# How to convert a keras model(.pb or .h5) to a .meta

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What would be the easiest way to convert a .pb or a .h5 model to a .meta file.

I have 2 programs, one generating a model a keras and one loading the same model in tensorflow 1.0. Can anyone help me with converting the keras model to a metagraphdef and get all trainable variables with weights,

Comment: You could try covnerting the [model to estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/estimator/model_to_estimator) and save estimator as meta and ckpt files.

Comment: @sebastian-szThank you so much. I will try that. Really appreciate the quick response